# I would like to know "SARIMA(statsmodels) parameter" [order] and [seasonal_order]. how should I choose?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, arima

my data (time-seriese) contains two-years data.(a value / day, row=360*2)

Now, I try to use SARIMA model from statsmodels.
I selected parameter(order and seasonal_order) randomly.
order=(1,0,1), seasonal_order=(0,1,0,360)
It was very fit to my data.

but I'm not understood in essence.
how should I choose parameter(p, d, q)?
order=(P,D,Q), seasonal_order=(p,d,q,s=360?)
can I read it from the ACF or PACF fig? or AIC, BIC from summary?

(I tried to choose it from "least AIC model". but it didn't work well)

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
SARIMA_1_0_1_010 = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(t3, order=(1,0,1), seasonal_order=(0,1,0,300)).fit()
print(SARIMA_1_0_1_010.summary())

residSARIMA = SARIMA_1_0_1_010.resid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(residSARIMA.values.squeeze(), lags=100, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(residSARIMA, lags=100, ax=ax2)


pred = SARIMA_1_0_1_010.predict(700, 1200)
plt.figure(figsize=(22,10))
plt.plot(t3)
plt.plot(pred, "r")
```

## and

```py
max_p = 3
max_q = 3
max_d = 1
max_sp = 0
max_sq = 0
max_sd = 0

pattern = max_p*(max_q + 1)*(max_d + 1)*(max_sp + 1)*(max_sq + 1)*(max_sd + 1)
modelSelection = pd.DataFrame(index=range(pattern), columns=["model", "aic"])

season = 360

num = 0

for p in range(1, max_p + 1):
    for d in range(0, max_d + 1):
        for q in range(0, max_q + 1):
            for sp in range(0, max_sp + 1):
                for sd in range(0, max_sd + 1):
                    for sq in range(0, max_sq + 1):
                        sarima = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(
                            t3, order=(p,d,q), 
                            seasonal_order=(sp,sd,sq,360), 
                            enforce_stationarity = False, 
                            enforce_invertibility = False
                        ).fit()
                        modelSelection.ix[num]["model"] = "order=(" + str(p) + ","+ str(d) + ","+ str(q) + "), season=("+ str(sp) + ","+ str(sd) + "," + str(sq) + ")"
                        modelSelection.ix[num]["aic"] = sarima.aic
                        modelSelection.ix[num]["bic"] = sarima.bic

                        num = num + 1

modelSelection[modelSelection.aic == min(modelSelection.aic)]
```

It didn't predict well....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem here is that `SARIMAX` is not a very good model to use when the seasonal effect is very long (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117953/very-high-frequency-time-series-analysis-seconds-and-forecasting-python-r/118050#118050).

In general, choosing the order of the model (e.g. p, q and P, Q) via information criteria is a good idea, but it is not a good idea to choose the differencing order (d or D) that way.

A python package that can help automate model selection while using the `SARIMAX` model is https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima.

However, I should repeat that this will generally not work well for models with a season length of 360.

Comment: thank you!
I have to learn more.
and your "URL" is so usefull, and gave me new knowledge!